# Does MPI guarantee non-overtaking property with mixed MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv?

Tags: c++, mpi

I have two MPI processes that exchange a buffer and an "ack" message, with a MPI_Isend and a MPI_Ircv, after that I use MPI_Waitall(...).

```
Process 0:
  MPI_ISend(...) // sends buffer
  MPI_IRecv(...) // gets ack
  MPI_waitwall(...)

Process 1:
  MPI_IRecv(...) // receives buffer
  MPI_ISend(...) // sends ack
  MPI_waitwall(...)
```

What I understand from the specification is that a sequence of ISends are guaranteed to be executed in order if they have the same tag, destination rank and communicator. But I am not sure if a given Isend can execute before this Irecev.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
​
int main() {
  int rank, size;
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  const int N = 400000000;
  const int VAL = 8;

 if (rank == 0) {
    std::vector<int> buffer(N, VAL);
    MPI_Request requests[2];
​
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    MPI_Isend(buffer.data(), N, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[0]);
    MPI_Irecv(nullptr, 0, MPI_BYTE, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[1]);
​
    MPI_Waitall(2, requests, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
​
    // time when we came back from the waitall
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto now_ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
                      now.time_since_epoch())
                      .count();
​
    std::cout << "[Rank 0][T=" << now_ns
              << "]: Rank 1 must have the buffer already!\n";
​
  } else if (rank == 1) {
    std::vector<int> buffer(N, 0);
    MPI_Request requests[2];
​
    MPI_Irecv(buffer.data(), N, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[0]);
    MPI_Isend(nullptr, 0, MPI_BYTE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[1]);
​
    MPI_Waitall(2, requests, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
​
    // time when we came back from the waitall
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto now_ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
                      now.time_since_epoch())
                      .count();
​
    std::cout << "[Rank 1][T=" << now_ns << "]: Received buffer!\n";

  }
 MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

I have written some MPI code (C++ bindings) to test it, and I expected the print form Rank 1 to always come BEFORE the print form Rank 0, but this is **not** always the case. Did I get the non-overtaking description wrong, is this test flawed, or this is expected behavior?

Comment: Outputs are generally **not** ordered, so if rank 0 printf first, the output of rank 1 might appear first in the logs.

Comment: And by the way, I do not expect ranks 1 to always `printf()` before rank 0.

Comment: `MPI_ISend()` are executed in order when they are executed on the **same rank** and with the same tag.

Comment: I see that outputs are generally not ordered, that is way I print the time that event occurred. But even that test is flawed, I guess, it does not prove anything. (Although it is more precise than the order of the print by itself.)

Comment: The thing I was testing was if the order of the send and the receiv with the same tag in the same rank were happening out of order.

Comment: There is no global order in MPI, and you generally cannot take timestamps for gospel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer step by step:

> What I understand from the specification is that a sequence of ISends
> are guaranteed to be executed in order if they have the same tag,
> destination rank and communicator.

It is guaranteed to be executed if all the Isends are posted by the same rank. For example,

```
Process 0:
  MPI_ISend(...) // sends buffer
  MPI_IRecv(...) // gets ack
  MPI_ISend(...) // sends buffer
  MPI_waitwall(...)
```

Here order of ISends is maintained, if they are sending to the same rank with the same tag in a single thread. This is what meant by Messages are **non-overtaking** in the standard.

> But I am not sure if a given Isend can execute before this Irecv.

Yes, Isend can execute before Irecv and vice versa since calling them will only initiate the operation.

> I have written some MPI code (C++ bindings) to test it, and I expected
> the print form Rank 1 to always come BEFORE the print form Rank 0, but
> this is not always the case.

This is not guaranteed for two reasons. 1) The order of printing is non deterministic. 2) The Order of completion of Isend and Irecv in two different ranks are nondeterministic.

> Did I get the non-overtaking description wrong, is this test flawed,
> or this is expected behavior?

Your understanding on non overtaking is wrong from the perspective that non overtaking only applies to the messages sent from a single rank not from a global perspective. The expected behaviour of the application is non deterministic (Either rank 1 or rank 0 can print based on the order of printing or order of completion).

Comment: Okay, I understood that these non-overtaking rules apply to a single rank only. But then, they do not apply to mixed sends and receives? In my example, can the following happen:
- Process 0 sends the buffer
- Process 1 starts the buffer receiving
- Process 1 starts the ACK send BEFORE the receive conclude
- Process 0 receives the ack

In process 0 the WaittAll returned, since we can do whatever with the buffer there and the ack arrived. In process 1 we still in the Waitall, since we did not received the buffer, but we already sent the ack.

Comment: In short, is the Order of completion of a Isend followed by an Irecv **in the same rank** non deteterministic?

Comment: Yes it is non deterministic.

Comment: the scenario you just described is a valid one.